# selecting rows from database between two dates giving wrong results

Tags: php, mysql

Selecting rows from database between two dates giving wrong results, the below query not working for me. I tried some answers, but this one not giving the correct results.I think, i am missing somewhere.

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Date BETWEEN '07/10/2015' AND  '07/14/2015'
```

changed to

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Date BETWEEN '07-10-2015' AND  '07-14-2015'
```

still not working!

Comment: It might be a date format issue. Does query think 14 is a month not day? Have you tried  other formats like YYYY-MM-DD? i.e. '2015-07-10'

Comment: Store dates using the correct data type and format.

Comment: Can you post how the data in the database actually looks like? Which values do you have in the "Date" column?

Comment: If this column is a varchar or char then this is a MAJOR screw up. Change the datatype to one of the date or timestamps.

Comment: highly recommended to add a `id` column. and then use of `id` for `between` !

Comment: @Sajad: Come on. You can't be serious?

Comment: @juergend ok !! can I chat with you [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83232/room-for-sajad-and-juergen-d) for a moment ?

Comment: I try to change the date colomn type to DateTime, and check.

Comment: when i changed the date colomn type it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's right, you can not use `BETWEEN` statement when the data type format is not a `DATE` or `DATETIME`, you must change the data type first.

BTW I just realized that even data type is a `DATE/DATETIME` format you can't use `/` in the SQL statement itself when using MySQL, versus SQL you can use `/` when the column data type is `DATE/DATETIME`. Just correct me if I'm wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Use the default date format `YYYY-MM-DD`

```
SELECT * FROM your_Table 
WHERE Date BETWEEN '2015-07-10' AND  '2015-07-14'
```

Comment: If the data in the database be like `/`, so ?

Comment: Then it is not stored as `date`. Don't store dates are string.

Comment: in sql if datatype is datetime you can do with `/` as well, I don't know in mysql

Comment: I tried this, but not still working, giving wrong results

Comment: @Chandu: What data type is your `date` column?

Comment: Please post the result of : DESCRIBE Table

Answer (score 0):

Erm, you're searching on "Date" but are you meant to be searching on "CreateDate"? That's what your image shows.